Create a cookie with the secure and httonly flags to display a banner
I am fairly inexperienced in PHP and JavaScript, but I am trying to create a small website for myself.
In this website, I want to display a small banner with some text inside when a new user enters my website (whichever the webpage is) for the first time. The banner has the following characteristics:

When displayed for the first time, it remains on the screen for 7 seconds (so the user can read it)
After its disappearance, the user can continue to browse the website and pages without seeing the banner anymore.

To do so, I thought to create a plugin (for WORDPRESS) that creates a cookie, let's call it banner_read. After the banner disappers, the cookie is created and the presence of the cookie does not cause the banner to be created. The cookie is only valid for the session (session cookie).
The first time I created the banner and the cookie via javascript code, also setting the ‘secure’ flag. The javascript code checks for the existence of the cookie and if it does not exist it creates the banner (with its settings). If I limit myself to this, the code works. In particular, the banner is displayed for seven seconds and the cookie is created after its disappearance, whichever is the first webpage displayed by the user.
Then, to be on the safe side and also out of curiosity, I wanted to set the ‘httponly’ flag as well, but from what I understand, it has to be done through php code, since the javascript code (to check the existence of the cookie) does not work if the httponly flag is set.
I have tried to create some php code to check the existence of the cookie and create it and javascript code to display the banner, but the code does not seem to work. In particular, the banner is not displayed and the cookie is created immediately.
Maybe for this simple cookie I don't need both the flags, but not knowing the subject in depth, I would like to play it safe.
First code - I report here the javascript code that works (the CSS file for styling is external):
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Cookie Manager
*/

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}


// Enqueue styles and scripts
function custom_cookie_manager_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-cookie-manager-style', plugins_url('css/custom-cookie-manager.css', __FILE__));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_cookie_manager_enqueue_styles');

// Add the cookie banner
function custom_cookie_manager_banner() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            if (!document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.trim().startsWith('banner_read='))) {
                var banner = document.createElement('div');
                banner.id = 'cookie-banner';
                banner.className = 'cookie-banner';
                banner.innerHTML = '<p>TEXT HERE</p>';
                document.body.appendChild(banner);
                
                setTimeout(function() {
                    banner.classList.add('hide');
                    document.cookie = "banner_read=true; path=/; Secure; SameSite=Strict";
                }, 7000); // 7 seconds
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_cookie_manager_banner');
?>

Second code - Here the PHP and Javascript code that does not work:
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Cookie Manager
*/

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}

// Enqueue styles and scripts
function custom_cookie_manager_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-cookie-manager-style', plugins_url('css/custom-cookie-manager.css', __FILE__));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_cookie_manager_enqueue_styles');

// Add the cookie banner
function custom_cookie_manager_banner() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['banner_read'])) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                var banner = document.createElement('div');
                banner.id = 'cookie-banner';
                banner.className = 'cookie-banner';
                banner.innerHTML = '<p>TEXT HERE</p>';
                document.body.appendChild(banner);
                
                setTimeout(function() {
                    banner.classList.add('hide');
                }, 7000); // 7 seconds
            });
        </script>
        <?php

        // Set cookie with HttpOnly and Secure flags
        setcookie('banner_read', 'true', 0, "/", "", true, true); // session cookie
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_cookie_manager_banner');
?>

Here is the CSS fyle:
/* css/custom-cookie-manager.css */
.cookie-banner {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 14px 20px 0 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cookie-banner.hide {
    visibility: hidden;
}

I have tried to create some php code to check the existence of the cookie and create it and javascript code to display the banner, but the code does not work properly.
Problems

The cookie is created immediately, even before the banner disappears (while I want after it disappears)
Even if the cookie is set, the banner is displayed if the user navigates from a web page to the home page (example.com/login to example.com). It does not happen between other pages.

Update
I tried an initial debug with some log messages within the javascript code and after setting the cookie
// Add the cookie banner
function custom_cookie_manager_banner() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['banner_read'])) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                console.log('Document loaded. Adding cookie banner...');
                var banner = document.createElement('div');
                banner.id = 'cookie-banner';
                banner.className = 'cookie-banner';
                banner.innerHTML = '<p>TEXT HERE</p>';
                document.body.appendChild(banner);

                console.log('Cookie banner added to the DOM.');
                
                setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log('Hiding cookie banner...');
                    banner.classList.add('hide');
                }, 7000); // 7 seconds
            });
        </script>
        <?php

        // Set cookie with HttpOnly and Secure flags
        setcookie('banner_read', 'true',0, "/", "", true, true); // session cookie
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log('set cookie..');
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_cookie_manager_banner');

As stated in the point 1, teh log message "set cookie.." appears before the log messages within the javascript code.
When the user navigates from a general web page to the homepage, even if the cookie is set, log messages are displayed.

What is your specific question about this code? "the code does not seem to work" isn't a particularly helpful statement; did the code do anything? What steps have you taken to debug this?

@mykaf They wrote: "In particular, the banner is not displayed and the cookie is created immediately."

If you use View Source, do you see the <script> block that's supposed to display the banner?

I have updated the question. At first the banner was not displayed, but now something has changed. Please read the new update. However, is the httponly flag needed of this kind of cookie?

Your first question suggests you don't understand the difference between client-side and server-side code. Everything in PHP runs before the HTML is sent to the client. I suspect the second issue may be due to caching of the home page, so it doesn't run PHP again.

Unless you want to disable caching, I suggest you go back to the original code that checks the cookie in JavaScript. What problem do you think you're solving by doing it in PHP?

I'm new to this and learning as I go. "Everything in PHP runs before the HTML is sent to the client." as I clicked on send the update I thought of this, without knowing it.I wanted to set the cookie with the HttpOnly flag, which is why I did it in PHP. However, considering the non-sensitive nature of the cookie, is it necessary to make it HttpOnly?
